# VS Code Python Wont Return After Call to Input

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a real odd behavior with my VSCode environment (macos v1.48.0) specifically with the Python extension. This only occurred recently, previously not a problem and debugging such code worked fine. My problem is I'm trying to debug a script that initially makes a user input request `data = input("text")` and after entering text into the terminal, the execution never resumes. I've ensured my launch settings script is valid and expected. I've actually gone through completely uninstalling and reinstalling VSCode. Additionally, the script runs as expected outside of VSCode. Obviously the motivation is to debug the code far beyond user input, and of course I can hardcode user input values to bypass these function calls, rest of the script runs fine, but I'm simply at a loss for why execution isnt resuming after this call to input... ??

Much thanks in advance.

Comment: further, integratedterminal is defined as the console value. its pure chaos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, you could refer to the following ways:

1. Please try to set a breakpoint for it to check whether it can be debugged successfully.
2. Since the [debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging) function of the python script is provided by the python extension, you could try to disabled other extensions and reinstall the python extension.
3. If the python extension you are using is the latest version, it is recommended that you downgrade it and use other versions of python extensions. For example:(python version: v2020.7.96456)

Comment: Downgraded to a different extension version. Thanks greatly.