# Python osX input command is giving an error in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, macos, input, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Code on OSX and I can't get the 'input()' command working.

when running, the prompt is shown but when I press enter, nothing happens until it runs out of time.

then, I got an error in the console saying :

```
zsh: command not found:
```

my code is just a single line with :

```
myInput = input("Type something :")
```

and it works well in the terminal, but not in visual studio code.

any idea ?

thanks,

Comment: What happens if you run the script from a Terminal window instead of from VSCode?

Comment: Same issue as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63506444/vs-code-python-wont-return-after-call-to-input) from this morning? Potentially a bad update?

Comment: yeah, it's the same issue it seems... weird... and yes, it runs on the Terminal. It's a VS Code issue only.

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue of Python extension on Linux and macOS. You need to avoid '2020.8.101144' version of Python extension( Click on the 'manage' cog on the Python extension, select 'Install another version ).

You can refer to this page: [https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/i9rllh/python_input_not_working_when_script_started_via/g1v7tls/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x​​​​​​​. He](https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/i9rllh/python_input_not_working_when_script_started_via/g1v7tls/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B.%C2%A0He) had run across a similar problem.